# Recycler View - Show only minimum elements and expand recycler view if user clicks expand

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I don't have any idea how to do . Please guide me to do the coding.. Actually , I am having recycler view and it has more than 10 items . But I need to show only top 4 items and need to add " view more " lbl or button ,if user clicks this lbl,recycler view show expand . I have attached one video. I don't know where to start.
https://vimeo.com/316969873

Comment: For your info , your video is private , we cannot see it

Comment: If you want expansion and collapse as well as you have fixed items in list then instead of using "Recyclerview", use "ExpandableListView"

Comment: @ManoharReddy ,now you can see it

Comment: So the simplest way will be take the View "View all recent location" below recyclerview . When initializing recycler view adapter , in list which you passing to adapter add only 4 items .
when user clicks on   "View all recent location" then add all items to list and update adapter .

Comment: @ManoharReddy ,what about height of recycler view ? Suppose if I have only 2 elements ???? My recycler view height is not updating dynamically .And wrap content not working.. I have only 100dp height for this part. So height of recycler view should be less than 100dp or equal to 100dp

Comment: Don't fix the height of recyclerview keep height wrap_content , keep complete layout in a nested scroll view . And for recycler view set nestedScrollingEnabled as false  programatically in java.